# Is EL&U getting boring? I thought it was, but then . .

Tags: discussion

Is EL&U getting boring?  I thought it was, but then I asked a question.  And was delighted by the answer and responses that resulted.  I'd like to suggest that all of us contribute more to this site by asking questions rather than answering them.

Comment: Is this a discussion, or a public announcement?  I don't see a lot of content here leaning towards it being a discussion; for example you said "but then I asked a question" and sort of left us wondering what it was without providing much detail.

Answer (score 8):

Interesting well-thought out questions are pretty essential to the site's well being. But they're pointless without answers, and they soon become boring if the answers themselves are of low quality. It is true though that the number of irrelevant, off-topic, and low quality questions AND answers on EL&U has risen in the last four or five months (my subjective impression), but occasionally the odd gem appears suddenly among the clutter and the weeds.

As for users contributing to the site with more questions, I presume you mean the higher rep users,  there are esteemed veterans who have never asked a question in their entire stay, but I value their contributions; i.e. answers, far more than someone who posts several questions which are either semi-literate or verbose (and perhaps lately my questions have fallen in the second category!) :)

Answer (score 0):

I think if you changed the name to EULa people would begin to assume it was boring, ignore it and leave but until then I think the site is fine.