# Can a placeholder text be added to the question body box?

Tags: feature-request, design, asking-questions

I posted this suggestion to [another post](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7550/59258), but thought it would be worth its own separate feature request.

Is it already possible to add a placeholder text to the question body box, or would the SE developers be able to add this functionality? If so, we can then discuss what the text should be. This placeholder text might be seen by more people who just ignore the side bar.

Here is a quick mockup I made:

[image: Image showing the new question page with a placeholder text in the question body]

Comment: I like this suggestion (as did 13 other people) , and wonder why it has received no answer or even a comment.  I don't see how this suggestion could do any harm, and it might do some good.  I think the site should be conservative, and this proposal is for a very conservative change.

Comment: It's a great suggestion. And should be a walk in the park for SE devs to implement it. I think this might be quite useful for other sites as well, that are struggling to cope up with questions which can be answered by commonly available references. This should be in MSE, IMO.

Comment: Currently being tested on Stack Overflow: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360260/have-we-started-trying-question-templates

Answer (score 8):

Yes, I love this idea. SE Devs should definitely add it. Quick and easy, and should be harder to ignore than the "How to ask" (which is off to the side).